# Jenkins trigger multibranch pipeline job with webhook

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am new into Jenkins and I've been struggling with the following issue:
I want to configure automated builds for a bitbucket repository in Jenkins when source code is pushed in any repository branch. For this, I configured multibranch pipeline for a repository in Jenkins and also a webhook in bitbucket which should trigger the job. However, I've been struggling with connecting this webhook with my multibranch pipeline. In multibranch pipeline there is no setting for webhook, only to scan "Periodically if not otherwise run".

Triggering a specific branch build (or at least to scan entire multibranch repo and detecting branches which were pushed) by a webhook seems like a relatively common use case to me, so I suppose this should be somehow possible, can someone please enlighten me on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Bitbucket Plugin?
If you have installed it you should see the option "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" under "Build triggers"

[Bitbucket build trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHqwj.png)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Manderino. I have Bitbucket plugin and can see the option you sent in configuration for pipeline. However, when configuring multibranch pipeline, I cant find any build trigger section.

Comment: It seems that I finally found other workaround for this issue -  
Multibranch Scan Webhook Trigger plugin allows to perform scan in the repository when webhook is triggered. I would prefer running just a single job instead of whole repo scan, but this suits my needs as well.